# Invalid template library specified. No module named 'crispy_forms.compatibility'

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Every time I try to run my django application locally on localhost using python3 manage.py runserver,  ge thte following error and i dont understand why. I have the latest version of crispy forms installed (1.11.2) and i have it on my requirements.txt, and installed on my venv. Can someone help me?

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templatetags/crispy_forms_filters 2.py", line 9, in <module>
    from crispy_forms.compatibility import lru_cache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms.compatibility'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_filters 2': No module named 'crispy_forms.compatibility'

^C%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    (venv) bermed28@Fernandos-MacBook-Pro semester-project-stack-overflowers % python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templatetags/crispy_forms_filters 2.py", line 9, in <module>
    from crispy_forms.compatibility import lru_cache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms.compatibility'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/semester-project-stack-overflowers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_filters 2': No module named 'crispy_forms.compatibility'
```

All I did was basically merge two branches that included some friont end changes with our back end changes, but now the application won't run at all because of this error

Comment: You also have it in your settings.py installed apps, right??

Comment: You somehow appear to have mixed up two versions of crispy forms? Looking at their repository they seem to have removed the compatibility module recently. Do you for some reason put your virtual environment in your git repositories?

Comment: I don't add the venv to the repo! And I do have it in my installed apps in settings.py

Comment: @FernandoBermúdez it seems your installation of crispy forms somehow got corrupted. Try `pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir django-crispy-forms` to reinstall the package.