# Docker Django_crispy_forms raise InvalidTemplateLibrary

Tags: python, django, docker, django-crispy-forms

I was developing a bookstore app using Django on Docker, I created a signup and login page, then utilized the django_crispy_forms for the signup and login page. Here is the commands flow：

```
docker-compose exec web pipenv install django_crispy_forms==2.0.0
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Lastly update the settings.py:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms', # new

    # local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
]

# django-crispy-forms
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4' # new
```

But when I check the logs with:

```
docker-compose logs
```

The console raise a error:

```
 raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. 
ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field': cannot import name 
'BoundField' from 'django.forms.forms' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py)
```

My Dockerfile code：

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=bookpostgresv2
      - POSTGRES_USER=bookpostgresv2
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=bookpostgresv2
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=bookpostgresv2
      - POSTGRES_USER=bookpostgresv2
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=bookpostgresv2
    depends_on:
      - db
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
psycopg2>=2.8
django-crispy-forms-ng==2.0.0
pipenv==2022.3.24
```

Comment: The version of crispy forms you have installed is old, and incompatible with the latest version of Django - you'll need to update to use a more recent version of crispy forms.

Comment: @solarissmoke I update the django_crispy_forms version to 1.13.0 and 1.14.0, but I still got Errors: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-crispy-forms-ng==1.13.0 (from versions: 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-crispy-forms-ng==1.13.0.

Comment: I change the django-crispy-forms-ng==2.0.0 to django-crispy-forms-ng>=1.12.0, but then encounter other errors:   ERROR: for 33458f335c7e_bookstoreprojectv2_web_1  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bookstoreprojectv2_web_1 (e97f93d26bc4ace00c2866276a9fd4e19825bfb23ad0078dca62f8acc7292b8c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bookstoreprojectv2_web_1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided in [66921240](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921240/invalid-template-library-specified-no-module-named-crispy-forms-compatibility), try to reinstall crispy form inside docker,

```
docker-compose execute <service> sh
pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir django-crispy-forms
```

Also I notice that you provide a vague versioning for Django (from 3.0 to 4.0) maybe incompatible with crispy-form?

Also try another python image (slim-buster maybe).

Hope you find solution.

Comment: Yes, It worked! @Abdelbaki Souid. I specify the Django version Django==4.0 in the requirements.txt file, and then used command 'docker-compose exec web pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir django-crispy-forms'. Finally yeah!